# Projection - Some of my data are in odd position

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, google-maps

Some of my data has this position lon: 181 / lat: 91
So when I try to draw them on the Google map:

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");

var wfsProtocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.v1_1_0({ 

               url: GeoServerURL,                  
               featureType: "Vector_Layer", 
       featureNS: "http://mapmap.org", 
       srsName: "EPSG:3857", 
               version: "1.1.0", 
               extractAttributes: true, 
               isBaseLayer: false, 
               visibility: true 
           });

wfsProtocol.read({            
    filter: filter,                      
    callback: processTheQuery, 
    scope: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ 
                   ratio: 1 
               })],
  })



Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("test", { 
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -85, 180, 85).transform(geographic,mercator),
displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, 
displayInLayerSwitcher: false 
         })



function processTheQuery(request) {  
if (request.data && request.data.bbox) {
var b = request.data.bbox;   
sExt = new OpenLayers.Bounds(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]); 
Layer.destroyFeatures();  
Layer.addFeatures(request.features);
map.zoomToExtent(sExt)
```

I got this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://myDomain/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.IllegalStateException: A transformation exception occurred while reprojecting data on the fly
A transformation exception occurred while reprojecting data on the fly
Latitude 91°00.0'N is too close to a pole.</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: While http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857 seems to be a "valid" code, your transformation exceeds the legal range (91°N does not exist...). Perhaps this posting is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556966/how-to-set-default-view-in-openlayers-without-restricting-bounds

Comment: As I understood, EPSG:3857 is the new Google projection instead of EPSG:900913. Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didnot understand markusN's Comment, but there is a problem in your data. You have mentioned that some of your data points have latitude as 91N and Longitude as 181.

This is an incorrect position as no such position exists on the earth. The range for Latitude is from +90 to -90 and the range of Longitude is from +180 to -180.

The coordinates of your points fall outside both these ranges. This is why your layer cannot be projected to Web Mercator.

If you check and correct your data, the problem should go away.

Comment: I received these data from its source and I cannot do anything to check if it's correct.  The only thing I thought about is finding a way to convert or reproject it but after your reply I understood that there is nothing I can do to fix it. right?

Comment: @Shadin: Yes. Till you correct these points or delete them, you will continue to get these errors. Garbage in, Garbage out, as they say.